# Antd Popover doesnt work with react-full-screen

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Popover } from "antd";
import { FullScreen, useFullScreenHandle } from "react-full-screen";

export default function App() {
  const handle = useFullScreenHandle();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FullScreen handle={handle}>
        <div className="App__inner">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <button onClick={handle.enter}>Click to FullScreen</button>
          <Popover placement="right" content={<span>tooltip</span>}>
            <button>hover me</button>
          </Popover>
        </div>
      </FullScreen>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is Popover doesnt work when i make App__inner component fullscreen. I have reproduced the issue here [codesandbox](https://b5v885.csb.app/). Please suggest any fix or alternatives

I was expecting the Popover to work as expected in fullscreen mode

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `Popover` is to create a div element in body , so when you do fullscreen the `div` is hidden. What you need to do is make use of `getPopupContainer` API of Popover and set the container body inside FullScreen for your Popover to be visible.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react"
import { Popover } from "antd";
import { FullScreen, useFullScreenHandle } from "react-full-screen";

export default function App() {
  const handle = useFullScreenHandle();
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <FullScreen handle={handle}>
        <div className="App__inner" ref={containerRef}>
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <button onClick={handle.enter}>Click to FullScreen</button>
          <Popover getPopupContainer={() => containerRef.current} placement="right" content={<span>tooltip</span>}>
            <button>hover me</button>
          </Popover>
        </div>
      </FullScreen>
    </div>
  );
}
```